# Different methods of including JavaScript files in DNN and how to use Defer and Async loading

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

I have seen a couple of forums where people mention that they can't use Defer and Async in DNN for JavaScript files. Is this true? See the two links below:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750303/how-to-use-asynchronous-non-blocking-javascript-with-dnn-client-resource-manag)

[Link 2](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/how-to-defer-parsing-of-javascript-cdns-performance)

Is there any new Developments or recent Updates that will allow this without having to use the Composite function turned on in DNN's performance tab?

Some people mention that you can include your JavaScript functions inside a $( document ).ready() function.

I would also like to know what is the difference between method 1 and 2 below for  including JavaScript files in DNN?

**Method 1 (ASP)**

```
          var moduleName = "MiniCart";
        //Include js file, prefix these files with this Type's name to avoid conflicts with multiple modules on the same page
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl scriptInclude = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Page.Header.FindControl(ID);
        if (scriptInclude == null)
        {
            scriptInclude = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("script");
            scriptInclude.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            scriptInclude.Attributes["src"] = this.TemplateSourceDirectory + "/Scripts/toastr.js";
            scriptInclude.ID = ID + $"{moduleName}_Toastr";

            Page.Header.Controls.Add(scriptInclude);

        }
    }
```

**Method 2 (Client Resource Manager)**

```
 ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(this.Page, "~/DesktopModules/MiniCart/Scripts/miniCartAjaxLoader.js", FileOrder.Js.DefaultPriority, "DnnFormBottomProvider");
```

**Method 3**

I know that you can also create a JavaScript Library Extension and install it like a normal module and reference the the name of the Library you need in your code behind like so:

```
JavaScript.RequestRegistration("Fancybox");
JavaScript.Register(this.Page);
```

There is already a couple of these libraries available for DNN on GitHub: https://github.com/EngageSoftware/DNN-JavaScript-Libraries

**Method 4**
You could also use dnnJsInclude to add the JavaScript file to your document:
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/client-resource-management-api

http://bdukes.github.io/Making-Full-Use-of-the-Client-Resource-Management-Framework/#/code-registration

Comment: I'm using defer in all my script tags with no problem (in dnn 7.x)

Comment: Can you give me a screenshot please?

Comment: Screenshot from what? just using `defer` attribute on `script` tag, nothing fancy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of DNN 9.2.0 you can use the `HtmlAttributesAsString` attribute to specify attributes which the Client Dependency Framework doesn't natively support. e.g. `HtmlAttributesAsString="defer:'defer'"` or `HtmlAttributesAsString="async:'async'"`.

This works for things like the crossorigin and integrity attributes too, e.g.

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsBootStrap" runat="server" FilePath="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ForceProvider="DnnFormBottomProvider" Name="bootstrap" Version="4.1.1" HtmlAttributesAsString="crossorigin:'anonymous',integrity:'sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T'" />
```

Outputs:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js?cdv=142" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency/wiki/Html-Attributes

Comment: This is very interesting. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: very well expalined and short answer, exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you include your JavaScript files in your modules. If you use the Client Dependency Framework there currently is not a way to specify async or defer. However, there is a open GitHub issue / Jira issue regarding this. If you use standard Script tags in your modules to include the JavaScript then you can use anything the Script tag supports.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I want to use the Client Dependency Framework to prevent duplicate JavaScript files. Using the normal script tags will cause duplicate JavaScript files to be loaded when having multiple modules. Hopefully the GitHub issue will bring new functionality or solutions. Does the priority setting in DNN make any difference or changing where it loads it? I guess it is not the same as Defer and Async.

Comment: You can set the script to be located at the top or bottom of the file and then set a priority order for sorting dependencies. For anything you can defer as long as possible set a low priority and set it to render at  the bottom.